# Zoom a imágenes en Javascript HTML PHP

Tags: html, div, zoom

Tengo por separados dos funcionalidades:

**1) Aplicar zoom a una serie de imágenes** cargadas mediante src en local.

**2) Generar un div** con los datos de una caseta la cual **contiene imágenes** que son mostradas para poder aplicarles el zoom del ejercicio **1)**.

El problema que tengo que por separado me funciona pero cuando quiero integrarlo no. Deseo que en el **2)** cuando quiero mostrar los datos de la cabaña, los cuales se muestran correctamente dentro del `div` "**mostrar_cabanas**" también me aplique la opción de poder ampliar cada imagen con un "`zoom`".

**Código Zoom imágenes: (Funciona).**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index.html</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cambiarimagen.css"/>
        <link href="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function cambiarImagen(imagen) {
                //Acceder y modificar propiedades de elementos y attr() para atributos.
                $("#grande").prop("src", imagen.src);
                $(".zoom").prop("href",  $("#grande").prop("src"));
                //Eliminamos el método zoomy.
                $(".zoomy").remove();
                //Eliminamos la clase padre de zoom.
                $(".zoom").removeClass("parent-zoom");
                //Volvemos a generar el método zoomy.
                $('.zoom').zoomy();
            }

            $(function() {
                $('.zoom').zoomy();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <br/><br/>
            <img class="peque" src="cabana1.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img class="peque" src="cabana2.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img class="peque" src="cabana3.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <a href="cabana1.jpg" class="zoom"><img id="grande" src="cabana1.jpg"/></a>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código Mostrar_Cabanas: (Funciona)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo1.jpg">
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST["buscar"]) && $_POST["check_in"]!="" && $_POST["check_out"]!=""){
                    $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
                    $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
                    //Llamamos al método "obtenerCabanasPorFecha" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
                    $datos = BD::obtenerCabanasPorFecha($check_in, $check_out);
                    echo "<br/>";
                    foreach($datos as $cabana){
                        echo "<b>".$cabana->getNombre()."</b>";
                        //Campo hidden (oculto) donde guardamos un valor que NO queremos mostrar.
                        echo "<form action='confirmacion_reserva.php' method='POST' name='mireserva'>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='idcabana' value='".$cabana->getIdcabana()."'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='check_in' value='".$check_in."'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='check_out' value='".$check_out."'/>";
                            echo "<center><input type='submit' name='reservar' value='Reservar'/></center>";
                        echo "</form>";
                        echo "<br/>";
                        //Cargamos las imágenes en un array $imagenes.
                        $imagenes = $cabana->getImagenes();
                        foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
                            echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='210' height='210'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        }
                        echo "<br/>";
                        $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCabana($cabana->getIdcabana());
                            foreach ($opiniones as $comentario){
                                $fecha = new DateTime($comentario["fecha"]);
                                echo "<br/><div id='opiniones'>".$fecha->format ('d/m/Y')."(".$comentario["idemail"].") - ".$comentario["opinion"]."</div><br/>";
                            }
                        echo "<hr/>";
                        echo "<br/>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**¿Cómo puedo integrar la funcionalidad del zoom en "mostrar_cabanas"?** Creo que sería recomendable hacer un div llamado "imagen_zoom" que cargue la primera imagen de cada cabaña.

**Esto he intentado:** Tengo un problema en el `div` "**imagen_zoom**".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Confirmación reserva</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_confirmacion.css">

        <link href="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function cambiarImagen(imagen) {
                //Acceder y modificar propiedades de elementos y attr() para atributos.
                $("#grande").prop("src", imagen.src);
                $(".zoom").prop("href",  $("#grande").prop("src"));
                //Eliminamos el método zoomy.
                $(".zoomy").remove();
                //Eliminamos la clase padre de zoom.
                $(".zoom").removeClass("parent-zoom");
                //Volvemos a generar el método zoomy.
                $('.zoom').zoomy();
            }

            $(function() {
                $('.zoom').zoomy();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "Reservar"...
        if(isset($_POST["reservar"])){
            $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"]; 
            echo "<div id='mostrar_imagenes'>";
                //Cargamos las imágenes en un array $imagenes.
                $imagenes = BD::obtenerImagenesCabana($idcabana);
                foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
                    echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='220' height='200' onclick='cambiarImagen(this)'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
                echo "<br/>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<br/>";

            echo "<div id='imagen_zoom'>";
                //Aqui iria la primera imagen del array imagenes, y sucesivamente al hacer click la seleccionada...
                //No se muy bien como elegir la primera y luego mediante click cambiarla... 
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<br/>";
            }
        }

        ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Este problema realmente parece más de HTML+JavaScript, siendo PHP más circunstancial. Deberías crear un [mcve] con lo que has intentado combinando los dos para que podamos ver el problema. Además, ¿recibes algún error en la consola?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Editado.

Comment: ¿Alguna posible solución?